# Scala class inheritance and method parameters

Tags: java, scala, oop

In Scala, I want to have the following traits and classes

```
trait Paper {
    def paint(args: Material): Unit
}

class WhitePaper extends Paper {
    override def paint(args: DarkMaterial): Unit = {
        darkMaterials.open()
    }
}


trait Material {
   def open() : Unit = {}
}

class DarkMaterial extends Material{
   override def open() : Unit = {
       print("Dark material")
   }
}
```

However, my IDE shows error for the override of method paint(args: DarkMaterial), even though DarkMaterial extends Material. Why is this wrong? Anyone knows how to fix it?

Thank you so much.

Comment: `paint(DarkMaterial)` does not override `paint(Material)`, because `paint(Material)` can accept _any_ `Material`; but `paint(DarkMaterial)` can only accept `DarkMaterial`.

Comment: Thx! But how can I fix it so that `def paint(args: DarkMaterial)` is acceptable?

Comment: Well, it's not an override. That's why you're getting the error. Whatever you're trying to do, this isn't it. Either `paint()` is supposed to accept any `Material`, or it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use type parameters to nail things down.

```
trait Paper[M] {
  def paint(args: M): Unit
}

class WhitePaper extends Paper[DarkMaterial] {
  override def paint(args: DarkMaterial): Unit = { // "override" not needed
    args.open()
  }
}
// Material and DarkMaterial are unchanged
```

Comment: We might want to consider making that `[M <: Material]` to indicate that the `M` type is intended to be a material, so you don't end up with a `Paper[String]`, depending on the use cases, of course.

Comment: @IanMcLaird Thanks! Your suggestion is very helpful.